# Randomize in JAVA

Tags: java, random

I have problem with generate randomize number in loop.

```
Random rand = new Random();
public MyPanel(){
    super();
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    for(int y = 0; y < 10; y++)
        for(int x = 0; x < 20; x++){
            int n = rand.nextInt(4); // it should be generate another n in each repeat of loop? 
            b[x][y] = new Baloon(x*25, y*25,n); // n means color of baloon, I need this to get balloons with randomize colors.
            add(b[x][y]);
        }
}
```

Comment: So you've got some code - what does it do compared with what you want it to do?

Comment: It looks like you want a bunch of balloons to appear but you are adding them all to the center of your layout.

Comment: What did you expect and what did you get instead?

Comment: As above, if your intent is to create a random integer between 0 (inclusive) and 4 (exclusive) on each iteration, the randomization logic itself seems fine... but can you describe the result compared to the expected result?

Comment: Something tells me that you may not want to use `BorderLayout`...